# MATLAB plotting syntax error?

Tags: matlab, plot

I watched a video titled "Writing a matlab program" and tried to use the syntax exactly, yet I still can't see how I've made an error...can you please help?

My code is simply

```
x= [-10:0.1:10];

y=2x^2-x + 1;

plot (x,y)
```

I'm getting a parse error at x and I have no idea what that means..

Comment: use `y = 2 * x .^ 2 - x + 1;`

Comment: As Kamtal mentions, the dot before the exponent is used to denote element-by-element multiplication since x is an array. Read this for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/times.html

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Voting to close this issue due to a simple typo.

Comment: @Kamtal - Voting to close this issue due to a simple typo.

Comment: Yes I agree.(useless text to reach # of characters)

Answer (score 2):

Matlab cannot parse `2x`. Multiplication requires the `*` symbol.  Either `*` or `.*` will work in this case.

Your *next* problem will be the use of `^` instead of `.^`  —this time you're going to have to include the dot. Google for "elementwise" operators in matlab to understand what difference the dot makes.